# how to isolate specific urls in angular app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, express, passport.js

What is the best practice in my situation.

I have angular app and express back-end API with passport.js to authorize.

for example, to connect twitter i have *GET* on *"/connect/twitter/"* in my express.js back-end. It proceeds with

```
app.get('/connect/twitter', passport.authorize('twitter-authz'));
```

in **angular app** when i click this link request doesn't work - it simply updates browser address bar with this url.

how can I isolate URLs for authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`, Angular will intercept clicks on links to give them this behavior. These are the exceptions to that rule:

1. Give the link a `target` attribute. Example: `<a href="/ext/link?a=b" target="_self">link</a>`
2. Link to a different domain. Example: `<a href="http://angularjs.org/">link</a>`
3. Link to a path starting with '/' that lead to a different base path when base is defined. Example: `<a href="/not-my-base/link">link</a>`

So, the easiest answer is probably to give the link a `target='_self'` attribute.

For more details, see "Html link rewriting" at the [Using $location guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location).